# Using enunciate, how can I have all rest APIs linked from one page when running against a multi module pom?

Tags: java, rest, maven-2, enunciate

I'm able to run mvn enunciate:docs against my multi-module pom where modules are complete implementations of services and the sites are created under each of those (ex. service1/rest/api/target/site/wsdocs/index.html) but I would like all the rest APIs linked in a single page via enunciate.

I'm only using enunciate to generate the API and example xml/json message bodies.

Is this possible, or do I have to create the site myself with some scripting or what have you?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution but you can create a site using the `maven-site-plugin` and specify the different APIs for your rest from there.
You need to create a site.xml and the links from there.

In the site.xml you can add a link in the menu by doing something like this:

```
<menu name="Overview">
        <item name="Description" href="index.html"/>
        <item name="API" href="api/index.html"/>
</menu>
```

In the previous example `api/index.html` is my API entry point.